# Mark a user as logged in using Django-two-factor-auth

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-two-factor-auth

I am using the [Django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) library for my sites login. Everything is working fine, however when I try to login and redirect a new user to their profile page after sign up using   `login(request, user)` I keep getting redirected to the login page.

The login works fine when the user re-enters their new login credentials however I want to redirect the user straight to their profile page after signup instead.

I am aware Django-two-factor-auth overides Django's built in authentication (Django.contrib.auth), however I am unsure why the login() function is not marking the user as authenticated.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def signup(request):
... 

  user = signup_form.save()
  login(request, user)
  return redirect('/profile')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add that to your settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'yourUrl' # this is the name of the url
```

Comment: I need to redirect after signup not after login.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Turns out the 'is_active' field of the newly created user was being modified by a model signal elsewhere in my code resulting in the user being redirected to the login page.